# How to convert negative longitude to a positive in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am reading in a text file and extracting values to display the longitude but from the text file, it is a negative value and need for it to be positive.

A sample of the text file that I have, in the format of (DDDMMSS.SS), named coordinates.txt:

```
Longitude : -0780417.04
```

Basically, it needs 359 added to the first 3 numbers (DDD or degrees), 59 to the next 2 numbers (MM or minutes) and 60.00 to the last 4 numbers (SS.SS or seconds).

**Note** : each split of numbers is a negative value

The desired output is:

```
281 55 43.0
```

The code that I have currently is:

```
with open('coordinates.txt', 'r'): as f:
    for line in f:
        header = line.split(':')[0]
        if 'Longitude' in header:
            longitude = line.split(':')[1].strip()[1:4] + " " + line.split(':')[1].strip()[4:6] + " " + line.split(':')[1].strip()[6:10]
            print longitude
```

How would I go about adding those additions to my current code?

Comment: also dont forget that what you read from a file is always of type string. Before doing your manipulations you are going to have to float() or int() the terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = line.split(':')[1].strip()
first = int(x[1:4]) + 359
second = int(x[4:6]) + 59
third = float(x[6:10]) + 60.0
print(first, second, third)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, pull the value into a variable. Leave it as a string:

```
key,value = line.split(':')
```

Next, perform your check. I don't know how you handle positive longitudes. I'm assuming you ignore them:

```
if key == 'Longitude' and value.strip().startswith('-'):
```

Next, disassemble the string into variables:

```
    neglong = value.strip()[1:]
    ddd = int(neglong[0:3])
    mm = int(neglong[3:5])
    ss_ss = float(neglong[5:])
```

Then do your math on the parts, and re-assemble however you like.